# Java not deleting a file which was created by itself

Tags: java, file

I've seen similar questions on here about `File.delete()` not working as expected, however this is slightly different in the way that Java has actually created the File, but won't delete it after it's finished with it.

```
File genFile = new File(parsed);
... sends file data across socket ... 
genFile.delete();
```

The generated file (`genFile`) was generated earlier in the program and written to, however when I try to delete it, the file just remains in the directory - no error messages etc. Any ideas as to what could be happening?

Comment: did you properly close the output stream after writing to the file? or any input streams after reading from it?

Comment: Set genFile = null; Often the file is not deleted unless the object is garbage collected.

Comment: please share the code that creates the file from java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to close() the file connection before trying to delete()

Answer (score 1):

`File.delete()` is bad, since it is silent about errors.

Try

```
java.nio.file.Files.delete(file.toPath());  // throws IOException
```

it might show you the reason why file can't be deleted. (or it might not:)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
genFile.close();
```

before

```
genFile.delete();
```

The stream would not have been flushed when you try to delete the file, so close the stream first and delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running under Windows or *Unix then that bit of information would be relevant.

Windows will not remove a file that is open by any application; close the file before removing.

Unix variants *should* go ahead and remove the file (release the inode).